# how can I calculated point of each user per day with sum all the points from beginning to that day in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have this data in clickhouse:

[image]

final point of each user in day is sum(point) from the beginning to that day.
e.g: point of user 1 in 2020-07-02 is 800 and in 2020-07-03 is 200.

I need this result: Point of each user per day:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select uid, d, t from (
select uid, groupArray(date) dg, arrayCumSum(groupArray(spt)) gt from
(select uid, date, sum(pt) spt from
(select 1 tid, '2020-07-01' date, 1 uid, 500 pt
union all 
select 1 tid, '2020-07-02' date, 1 uid, 300 pt
union all 
select 1 tid, '2020-07-03' date, 1 uid, -600 pt)
group by uid, date
order by uid, date)
group by uid) array join dg as d, gt as t

┌─uid─┬─d──────────┬───t─┐
│   1 │ 2020-07-01 │ 500 │
│   1 │ 2020-07-02 │ 800 │
│   1 │ 2020-07-03 │ 200 │
└─────┴────────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to know the point of each user everyday not just in days that has transaction right now I have this result:

2020-07-02 500
2020-07-06 650
2020-07-07 1150
2020-07-08 1650
2020-07-12 1850
2020-07-13 1970
2020-07-15 470
2020-07-25 670
2020-08-03 780
2020-08-10 910
2020-08-11 1030
2020-08-12 1410
2020-08-15 1530

I need to know the point of this user in "2020-07-03 ,2020-07-04 ,2020-07-05"  is 500

Comment: For missing days you can join the result with some calendar table. Or use timeslots function. Or order by with fill from date.